# C#: Distinction with containing List

Tags: c#, list, distinct

I have a List of instances of a class. Each instance contains a IList-property and a object of a custom class. Now I want to drop all distict instances in this List, where the elements of the containing IList-Property and the Multi-Property of the MyMulti-Class are equal. I want to remain only the one element in the List, where the "First"-property of  the "someData"-Property is the lowest.
My suggestion was, to group the elements of the List by the containing IList-Property and the "Multi"-property of the "SomeData"-property and then sort it by the "First"-property of the "SomeData"-Property and select the first Element of each group.

I need it as performant as possible. Anyone any ideas?

Example:

```cs
class myClass
{
    public IList<String> SomeStrings { get; set; }
    public MyMulti SomeData { get; set; }

    public myClass(MyMulti data, params string[] strings)
    {
        SomeData = data;
        SomeStrings = strings;
    }
}

class MyMulti
{
    public int First { get; set; }
    public int Second { get; set; }

    public int Multi
    {
        get
        {
            return First * Second;
        }
    }

    public MyMulti(int first, int second)
    {
        First = first;
        Second = second;
    }
}
```

```cs
var mc1 = new myClass(new MyMulti(6, 4), "0", "1");
var mc2 = new myClass(new MyMulti(3, 8), "0", "1");
var mc3 = new myClass(new MyMulti(7, 3), "0", "1");
var mc4 = new myClass(new MyMulti(2, 35), "0", "2");
var mc5 = new myClass(new MyMulti(5, 4), "1", "1");
var mc6 = new myClass(new MyMulti(7, 10), "0", "2");

IList<myClass> aList = new List<myClass>(){mc1, mc2, mc3, mc4, mc5, mc6};

var query = aList.GroupBy(x =>
    new
    {
        x.SomeData.Multi,
        x.SomeStrings   
        // don't work cause this will compare the lists 
        // not the containing elements
    })
    .Select(x=>
        x.OrderBy(y=>
            y.SomeData.First)
            .First());
```

Result should be: mc1 and mc2 grouped and then drop mc1, mc3 own group, mc4 and mc6 grouped and then mc6 droped, mc5 own group --> mc2, mc3, mc4, mc5 should remain

## EDIT:

If I first sort the List by the MyClass.SomeData.First-property and then use the List.Distinct()-method and a custom IEqalityComparer implementiation I get, what I'm searching for. But is this the most performant way to do this?

```
public class myClassEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<myClass>
{

    public bool Equals(myClass x, myClass y)
    {
        if (!x.SomeData.Multi.Equals(y.SomeData.Multi))
            return false;
        else
            if (x.SomeStrings.AsEnumerable()
                   .SequenceEqual(y.SomeStrings.AsEnumerable()))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(myClass obj)
    {
        int hCode = obj.SomeData.Multi;
        foreach (var item in obj.SomeStrings)
        {
            hCode = hCode ^ item.GetHashCode();
        }
        return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why dont you try Distinct() method might do your wrok

[`List.Distinct();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your thought. I tryed to define my own implementation of IEqualityComparer<MyClass>. But there I can't pick the lowest "MyMulti.First", it picks just anyone.

Comment: Implement IComparable<T> instead of IEqualityComparer<T>

Comment: I don't get how to combine IComparable<T> with List.Distinct(). List.Distinct() needs Equals and GetHashCode, IComparable only provides CompareTo. I thought this is only for sorting?

Answer (score 0):

you GetHashCode function may slow thing down.
Hash code is used to balance hash table and for the best performance, a hash function must generate a random distribution for all input. You should try:

```
public int GetHashCode(myClass obj)
{
    return obj.SomeData.First ^ obj.SomeData.Second;
}
```

You may test performance using System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch and loop 100000 to 1000000 times.

Comment: Actually you can get upto 30% performance gain if you have big string arrays and huge number of elements